# Row couldn't be returned from a DataTable C#

Tags: c#, select, datatable, datarow

I have a DataTable with data, which I can debug in VisualStudio and verify the values. And I can see the column '*Path*' value is available in DataTable object but I couldn't retrieve the Row using *Select*. Please help me to retrieve  the Row. Below is the piece of code I'm trying with:

Note: there's a space in *path* value  [`C:\Program Files<space>(x86)`]

```
string path = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\1.0.0.0\Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe"
string condition = string.Format("Path = '{0}'", path);
DataRow row = myDataTable.Select(condition).FirstOrDefault(); //returns null
```

Comment: Is it a problem of case sensitivity? If you can confirm that the value exists as you have spelled it (check also any whitespace at the end) then there is no reason for this code to fail

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your code but there is no problem at all (as expected). As I have said there is something that is not what it looks in your path stored in the database. Probably some spaces are not really spaces. Try to copy/paste the value from your database row in an editor and look at the hexdecimal values of those spaces. All should be 0x20.

Comment: yes @Steve , spaces creating the actual problem and it has been resolved by removing spaces while comparing(checking with condition). but I don't think this is a right way to remove spaces in both sides while comparing, is there any better way?

Comment: How do you have defined your Path column? It should be a nvarchar column. If you use char(x) then db adds spaces to fill the column size.

Comment: @Steve this is not reading from database but it is reading the file path from the local machine, and obviously the `path` variable is a `string`

Comment: Well, in any case you should look at how do you store those values in your table and trim at that point the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DataRow row = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault( dr => dr.Field<string>("Path" ) == path);
```

Comment: it didn't work. there's a space in path value as I've modified the question. please verify and modify your solution. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that at least one row exists in datatable with that Path value?

Comment: yes, row exists and I can verify with debugger in Visual Studio. this is strange problem!

Comment: Can you share Path value in datatable please?

Comment: this is the exact value:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VsHub\1.0.0.0\Microsoft.VsHub.Server.HttpHost.exe`

Comment: As @Steve mentioned in comments, try manually copy/paste path value from datatable and check. Might be there is slash(/) and backslash(\) difference..

Comment: thanks @ikram, problem is solved by removing spaces while comparing. is there any better for the same?

Comment: It is strange... have no idea :)